# C# send and receive tcp packet via web app

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, tcpclient, tcpserver

Hi
We are writing a unique project. I was wondering if someone could point me us in the right direction, as I am not familiar with tcp programming.

We talk to an external system. I send a tcp packet and receive the tcp response. This needs to work from a page in a web application, continuously polling every x msecs

The proposed message length is 8 bytes, no information about the start or end of message is transmitted. Message structure:
| byte 0 | byte 1 | byte 2 | byte 3 | byte 4 | byte 5 | byte 6 | byte 7 |

Message delimiters are:
| byte 0 | = 0x02 (stx) 
and 
| byte 7 | = 0x03 (etx)

My send message:
| stx | ‘s’ | ‘b’ | ‘0’ | ‘0’ | ‘0’ |‘0’ |etx |

My recv message:
| stx | ‘S’ | ‘B’ | ‘0’ | '1' | ‘0’ | ‘0’ | etx |

Questions:

Should I use the tcpCLient/Listener classes or Sockets classes?

Whats the best way to get the web page to continuously poll and send/receive these packets every x ms?

Comment: The best way would be not to use a web page for continuous communication, use a service.

Comment: ok, thanks, I was thinking that, but I need to display the results of the tcp response into a flash message to user.

Comment: your web page makes an AJAX call to your server. It could make a call to a handler, a service, whatever, doesn't matter. Your handler, then makes the call out to the external system using TCP. That is whatever code you have currently that does this. The response from the external system is sent back as a response of your handler tothe web page. The web page does what it need to do with this data.

Answer (score 0):

What you are proposing basically can't be done, because Javascript does not support direct TCP/IP. You would have to run the TCP process on the server, and use an asynchronous update method to display the results on your web page.

To display the results asynchronously on your page you would have to use Ajax and Comet. Comet offers you basically three options:

1. Have your Javascript poll the server with an Ajax request called from a timer callback; this has all the disadvantages of polling,
2. Use a "long poll" which essentially means do an asnychronous call to your web site that blocks until it has a result; this doesn't scale well since it locks an IIS thread for every client web page,
3. Use a comet server and associated client side library, is the best route but usually involves spending money.

There is lots of information on Comet and Ajax on the web.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into [WebSockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSockets) for your client side communication, though support is very limited at the moment.

Another option would be to use a `.swf` file as an intermediary for your `TCP` communication.  See http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/Socket.html.  Every time you receive a packet of interest you could use `ExternalInterface` to pass data out of the flash movie and to eagerly waiting javascript!

Comment: Flash, like JavaScript will not allow cross domain communication unless the other website has a cross domain policy file. This is more work that it needs to be (adding Flash to the mix).

Comment: Thanks, wow I never realised flash had this built into it. I'm looking into websockets now, I think this is what I need.